# VBA Select from dropdown list while filling webform

Tags: html, excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I'm quite new to VBA and HTML. I try to write a VBA macro which fill in a web form.
I am struck at a point where I have to select value from the dropdown list.

```
 Sub test()

 Dim IE As Object
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = True
 IE.Navigate ("https://www.fakturowo.pl/wystaw")
 Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Loop

Set doc = IE.Document

doc.getElementById("rodzaj").Value = 26

doc.getElementById("miasto").Value = "XYZ"
doc.getElementById("nazwa_sprzedawca").Value = "XYZ"
doc.getElementById("ulica_sprzedawca").Value = "XYZ"
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<select name='rodzaj' id="rodzaj" onchange="javascript:submit();">
  <option value='47'>Dobowy raport fiskalny</option>
  <option value='24'>Dowód dostawy</option>
  <option value='27'>Dowód dostawy (tylko ilość)</option>
  <option value='7'>Dowód wewnętrzny</option>
  <option value='42'>Eksport towarów</option>
  <option value='48'>Eksport usług</option>
  <option value='49'>Eksport usług (VAT-EU 28b)</option>
  <option value='62'>Faktura</option>
  <option value='21'>Faktura (bez vat, dawny rachunek)</option>
  <option value='45'>Faktura (odwrotne obciążenie bez vat)</option>
  <option value='35'>Faktura (odwrotne obciążenie z vat)</option>
  <option value='69'>Faktura MPP (mechanizm podzielonej płatności)</option>
  <option value='0' selected>Faktura VAT</option>
  <option value='44'>Faktura VAT MP</option>
  <option value='26'>Faktura VAT RR</option>
  <option value='5'>Faktura VAT marża</option>
```

Many thanks!
Gosia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must trigger the html change event of the dropdown. To do that you must save the html dropdown element do an object variable. So you can give it to the needed function to trigger html events.

**I have commented the relevant code parts:**

```
Sub test()

  Dim IE As Object
  Dim nodeDropDown As Object 'Needed to set the dropdown as DOM Object
  Dim doc As Object
  
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate ("https://www.fakturowo.pl/wystaw")
  Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set doc = IE.Document
  
  'set the dropdown as DOM object
  Set nodeDropDown = doc.getElementById("rodzaj")
  'Change the value of the dropdown
  nodeDropDown.Value = 26
  'Trigger the html change event of the dropdown
  Call TriggerEvent(doc, nodeDropDown, "change")
  'Wait to load the page new after changing the dropdown value
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
  
  doc.getElementById("miasto").Value = "XYZ"
  doc.getElementById("nazwa_sprzedawca").Value = "XYZ"
  doc.getElementById("ulica_sprzedawca").Value = "XYZ"
End Sub
```

**This is the procedure to trigger a html event**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer it was really helpful, and works on most dropdowns. Unfortunately, I found one that above did not work. Will you be able to help? (<span data-toggle="dropdown" class="pointer1" id="dane_oznaczenie_sprzedawca_select">Sprzedawca</span> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon pointer1 fa-angle-down" data-toggle="dropdown"></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('dane_oznaczenie_sprzedawca_select').innerHTML='Sprzedawca';document.forms.form.elements['sprzedawca[dane_oznaczenie]'].value='0';">Sprzedawca</a></li>)

Comment: @Gosia Through the posted html snippet you can see that there is no html dropdown. Probably it is one that was created via a JS framework like jQery or React using other html elements. Such dropdowns work completely different and I can't offer a blanket solution.

Comment: Many thanks!!! I was sure that this is a dropdown. When you wrote that this is not, it was really easy to change it :) Now everything work perfect, except downloding the PDF file (but I think it is to hard for me right now :) )